# Split table column itext7

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, itext7

In a windows form application, I have a table on which I dinamically add data. I need to split the table on more pages if the number of column are too much.
I add this image as an example:
[As you can see I have too many columns and some of them are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjJNp.png)

I would like to do something like: after a defined number of columns (let's say 25) split the content of the table to another page with the remaining data.

This is how I create the table:

```
table = New Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(tableCells)).UseAllAvailableWidth()
```

where tableCells is an integer where I have the number of all the columns of my document.
Then I iterate and populate the table, add the headers and footers and so on.

Is there an option or a workaround to set an "automatic" table split over more pages if the columns are more than a defined number? Or should I create another table with all the things I've done for the main with the remaing column and repeat all the coding (i.e. footers, headers, top paragraph headers...)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there are a few steps to create a 'Paged Listing'

if you want 25 items per page. simply only return the index range from 0 to 24. into the table. then simply stop the code at that point to avoid another listing.

```
For index as integer = 0 to 24
   SomeDatasource(index)
next
```

Then, Listen to a Querystring like http://example.com?page=1.

then simply calculate the offset for that page (25 * request.querystring("page"))

simply only return the index range into the table from 0 + offset to 24 + offset

```
For index as integer = 0 +(25 * request.querystring("page")) to 24 + (25 * request.querystring("page"))
   SomeDatasource(index)
next
```

Add a button that goes to next page. when button is clicked do:

```
response.redirect("/mypage.aspx?page=" & (request.querystring("page") + 1) )
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm developing a win form application, I use itext7 for generate a pdf in a win form application, is not an aspx page